# Devise with Sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra, devise

Does anyone had installed [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem with Sinatra?

Devise is based on Warden and so it should work on Sinatra, I couldn't find any related info about how to implement it.

Comment: It is pretty rails-centric: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Devise is really just a Rails-centric wrapper with nice helpers for [warden](https://github.com/wardencommunity/warden), which is the underlying Rack authentication framework.  So if you're using Sinatra in conjunction with Rails, you can use Devise in your Rails app, and use warden directly in your Sinatra app, and they will see the same user session data.

So no, you can't use Devise directly within your Sinatra app, but if you're building a modular app with some pieces in Rails, and other pieces in Sinatra, you can use Devise/Warden among the components.

Answer (score 7):

There is also https://github.com/jsmestad/sinatra_warden available.

Answer (score 6):

Devise is designed for Rails only. You can't use it with Sinatra.

You can check out:

https://github.com/maxjustus/sinatra-authentication

http://www.gittr.com/index.php/archive/sinatra-basic-authentication-selectively-applied/

https://gist.github.com/243611

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get it working. There were a few main aspects:

1. Get Devise working with Rails (Devise is a Rails app, won't work without it)
2. Setup the mapping (route) on Rack level to support both Rails and Sinatra
3. Share the sessions between Rails and Sinatra
4. Setup Warden and make it available to Sinatra

Here is most relevant part of code from /config.ru:

```
    #

    # ...

    # Rest with Rails
    map "/" do
      run MyApp::Application
    end

    # Anything urls starting with /slim will go to Sinatra
    map "/slim" do

      # make sure :key and :secret be in-sync with initializers/secret_store.rb initializers/secret_token.rb
      use Rack::Session::Cookie, :key => '<< see, initializers/secret_store.rb >>', :secret => '<< copy from initializers/secret_token.rb >>'

      # Point Warden to the Sinatra App
      use Warden::Manager do |manager|
        manager.failure_app = AppMain
        manager.default_scope = Devise.default_scope
      end

      # Borrowed from https://gist.github.com/217362
      Warden::Manager.before_failure do |env, opts|
        env['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST"
      end

      run AppMain
    end
```

See, http://labnote.beedesk.com/sinatra-warden-rails-devise for a complete solution.

Comment: You should have developed your app in Rails

Comment: @AMBasra, I needed a simpler framework to develop a CRUD api, Sinatra looked like a tools of the right size for the tasks.

Comment: I meant you are running rails server with your app. So it's no more lighter. Why use two frameworks if you can do everything in one. Production environment would also be running both rails and sinatra.

Comment: I think it is still lighter for the server load. Once authenticated, subsequent requests goes to Sinatra only (beside the shared session middleware). It is also lighter for development. Rails is MVC framework, when you don't need the VC and routes, it gets into the way a little bit every time.