# API Authentication for Sinatra

Tags: ruby, api, backbone.js, sinatra

I'm create a simple Sinatra app to serve as an API endpoint for a Backbone.js application. It will have a classic CRUD routes. The website that will function from this API backend is using Twitter for authentication. So the users sign in to Twitter to authorize the application and then come back to the application where their account is then created.

Instead of creating the account, I want to send the account creation request to the API and then have the API serve the website and do all the get, put, post, delete methods.

Is there a standard way to handle authentication? I'm not sure what to send to the API from the website for each user to "sign in".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the standard way but I used [omniauth-twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter/) and sinatra once and I was happy with it.

Comment: I agree. By far the easiest way I've found (quick guide to setting it up here http://codebiff.com/omniauth-with-sinatra)

Comment: I'm sure there are a lot of authentication gems. I guess my question was more about the logistics of making sure that every API call is properly authenticated. It doesn't seem like using session is possible on the API end? So do they send along their credentials each time? But since it's twitter, they wouldn't necessarily have credentials. I'm just confused about the communication between the website and the API layer...I have the web application part authenticating very simply with Twitter and that all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Warden seems to be the standard way to handle authentication for Rack.

Have a look at this post: [Sinatra Warden with existing Ruby on Rails application that uses Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5700936/859762)